# Tableau API Query View Image doesn't work always (v 3.12)

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to connect to tableau via REST API (v 3.12) to download some published views (with live query to BigQuery as data source) as PNG image. The API doesn’t work sometimes and returns empty image of the view (It still gets the view's skeleton but not the underlying data). I am using the [View data API](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_workbooks_and_views.htm#query_view_data) to get the data in a CSV format for the view to check the data is available in view or not but it returns `NaN`

View Data API: `GET /api/3.12/sites/site-id/views/view-id/data?maxAge=10`

View Image API: `GET /api/3.12sites/site-id/views/view-id/data?maxAge=10`

Issue I am facing is, not always the API endpoints return data, Out of 4 reports I am trying to download, 3 reports are working fine, just the one that is trying to download first doesn't work, my guess, its the first one that doesn't work